# Worker-ы убивают IE11

Tags: javascript, html5, internet-explorer, webworkers

Выполнение этого небольшого [теста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343913/how-to-create-a-web-worker-from-a-string):

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var response = "self.onmessage=function(e){ if (console && console.time) console.time('worker '+e.data); var l = 20000, p = 1; for( var i = 1; i <= l; i++ ) for( var j = 1; j <= l; j++ ) p += Math.log( j / i ); if (console && console.timeEnd) console.timeEnd('worker '+e.data); postMessage( 'Worker '+e.data+': Отработал и ушел в отпуск!' ); self.close(); }";

var blob;
try {
   blob = new Blob( [response], {type: 'application/javascript'} );
} catch (e) {
   window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder;
   blob = new BlobBuilder();
   blob.append(response);
   blob = blob.getBlob();
}
var worker = new Worker( URL.createObjectURL(blob) );

worker.onmessage = function(e) {
   if (console) console.log( e.data  );
   // worker.terminate();
};
worker.postMessage( 'А' );
```

Приводит к выдаче сообщения в IE11:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибка выдается при [обоих вариантах завершения работников](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/workers/basics/):

- self.close();
- worker.terminate();

Без этих строк все отлично работает, кроме того что по мере вызова работников увеличивается число созданных объектов...

Как в IE прервать выполнение работника (worker) до завершения его программы без падения браузера ?

Comment: Хорошо оформленный вопрос, есть вся информация. Почему ж никто не отвечает...

Comment: мало кто работает с воркерами, особенно в IE, я работаю, но только в хроме.

Comment: так тоже падает ?(нет IE под рукой) http://plnkr.co/edit/netVzv8PENIq8M2JlBgy?p=preview

Comment: Нет, так IE не умирает... Но держать скрипт на сервере в пару строк с импортом и обработчиком onmessage как-то не правильно.

Comment: @t1nk почему ? закешируется и все. ещё есть подозрение что мусорщик приходит за blobUrl, попробуйте сделать переменную а не напрямую в new вставлять.

Comment: Дело в том, что все скрипты обфусцируются и объединяются (за исключение сторонних библиотек) - один файл для пользователя. В файлах имеются классы предназначенные для использования в worker-ах. Поэтому скелет worker-ов объявляется непосредственно в html. Далее собирается код worker-ов. Описанный вами способ требует генерации отдельного файла для worker-ов, что потребует изменения архитектуры приложения и подхода к разработке. А этим заниматься сейчас времени уже не дадут. Поэтому забили на IE. Тем более есть проблема важнее - нехватка памяти на слабых машинах (с 2 ГБ и Win7). Но спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за [проблемы безопасности](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/801810/web-workers-from-blob-urls-in-ie-10-and-11)(*англ.*) - создание `worker`-ов в IE10-11 посредством `Blob`-конструктора не представляется возможным. Вам остаётся использовать URL и внешний скрипт или data-URI. Вот например

```
var worker = new Worker('data:application/javascript,' +
                         encodeURIComponent(response) );
```

#### обновление

К сожалению IE10+ не поддерживает и вариант с `data-URI`.

[На stackowerflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10372280/1816872) (*англ.*)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как я написал в вопросе, с созданием worker-ов в IE11 проблем нет. Веселье начинается при попытке уничтожения - браузер просто падает. Поскольку проблему решить не удалось, обошли этот момент использованием очереди из N (~ число ядер) worker-ов. Минус при этом в том, что потоки висят с момента создания в памяти. Кроме того пришлось увеличить объем их кода. Что в итоге отразилось на системных требованиях клиента - в некоторых случаях не хватает 2 Гб RAM (Win7 и FF, реже Chrome и IE). Но зато хотя бы скорость вычислений немного выросла, что конечно плюс.

Comment: @t1nk, так а Вы пробовали создавать worker не Blob-ом а передавая ему URL на внешний файл, тогда тоже падает при закрытии?

Comment: Если код тянуть не Blob-ом, а URL - то ошибка не возникает

Comment: В проблема падения IE решается, описанным вами способом, что было опробовано ещё до задания вопроса. И хотя данный подход не является приемлемым для исходной задачи, вопрос все таки закрываю - он сам по себе решен.